# Why does Eugene repeatedly demand Arlene to ask him what happens next?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, pay-it-forward

In **[Pay It Forward](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0223897/)**, Eugene talks about his father's behavior to Arlene. But he repeatedly demands Arlene to ask him what happens next.

> Eugene: Did he hurt you, Eugene? **Ask me**!
>
> Eugene: Now **ask me** what happened that night.

Why does he do that?